# How to manage more than one instance of an activity?

Tags: java, android

In my application I will create multiple instances of one activity. That's ok, but I need to bring to the screen one of the previous instances if user choose it. Is there an id or something to identify different instances of an activity?

Comment: Can you describe the use case ? I think there might be better implementation choice than starting multiple activities. You might consider using fragments

Comment: I agree, why would you want to keep multiple instance of an Activity ? Is there that much of data to set into it ? For your question, how are you storing those instance ? Use a Set to get them in the order you want

Comment: Yes maybe fragments are more suitable for my case, because of I am new on android development, I could not find the right way yet. In my case each instance will look like a small application. User can do some operations in those instances and if he want he can switch between instances.  And states of the instances must be stored. If one is brought to the screen, it should look the same as user had left it before.

Comment: I would not use multiple instance here, simply use a Collection to store the status of the Activity (every Objects of the screen you need) to be reloaded later. This will be easier, safer and probably lighter. Something like a Memento Pattern

Comment: but it is highly probably that there will be sub fragments in activity so I should keep the navigation history of fragments for each instance. And each fragment in history should keep its component states too. Is it possible too? Thanks for your interest.